# Como evitar que se me dupliquen las columnas en un join en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo que obtener los jugadores con al menos 30.000 puntos en su carrera y que hayan obtenido por lo menos un premio y que este vivos

mi código es el siguiente:

```
query = '''SELECT players.playerID, lastName, SUM(points) AS AllPoints, award, deathDate
    
    FROM players
    
    INNER JOIN players_teams 
    ON players.playerID = players_teams.playerID  
    
    INNER JOIN awards_players
    ON players.playerID = awards_players.playerID  

    GROUP BY players.playerID, lastName, award , deathDate
    
    HAVING SUM(points) > 30000 AND award IS NOT NULL and deathDate = "0000-00-00"
    
    '''

puntos2 = pd.read_sql(query,db)
puntos2
```

pero la suma d punto se hace mal ya que al haber ganado un jugador mas de un premio se vuelve a repetir dicha suma. No se como evitar que se reptan las columnas. Si filtros solo los jugadores que tienen más de 30.000 puntos me da la siguiente columna:

```
playerID    lastName    AllPoints
0   abdulka01   Abdul-Jabbar    38387.0
1   chambwi01   Chamberlain 31419.0
2   ervinju01   Erving  30026.0
3   jordami01   Jordan  32292.0
4   malonka01   Malone  36928.0
```

Mi problema resumido es que si tengo estas dos tablas:

```
Jugador Puntos
Abdul   50000
Jordan  60000

Jugador Premios
Abdul   A
Abdul   B
Abdul   C
Jordan  D
Jordan  E
```

Al unir ambas con un JOIN obtengo esto:

```
Jugador Puntos  Premios
Abdul   50000   A
Abdul   50000   B
Abdul   50000   C
Jordan  60000   D
Jordan  60000   E
```

y quiero evitar que se repitan. Probe con un distintc pero me da error.

gracias por la ayuda

mi resultado es tal que asi:

| playerID | lastName | AllPoints | award | deathDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abdulka01 | Abdul-Jabbar | 191935.0 | All-Defensive First Team | 0000-00-00 |
| abdulka01 | Abdul-Jabbar | 230322.0 | All-Defensive Second Team | 0000-00-00 |
| abdulka01 | Abdul-Jabbar | 383870.0 | All-NBA First Team | 0000-00-00 |
| abdulka01 | Abdul-Jabbar | 191935.0 | All-NBA Second Team | 0000-00-00 |
| abdulka01 | Abdul-Jabbar | 76774.0 | Finals MVP | 0000-00-00 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| wilkido01 | Wilkins | 106672.0 | All-NBA Second Team | 0000-00-00 |
| wilkido01 | Wilkins | 53336.0 | All-NBA Third Team | 0000-00-00 |
| willibu01 | Williams | 33568.0 | All-Defensive First Team | 0000-00-00 |
| willibu01 | Williams | 33568.0 | All-Defensive Second Team | 0000-00-00 |
| worthja01 | Worthy | 32640.0 | All-NBA Third Team | 0000-00-00 |

pero en cambio si solo busco jugadores con mas de 30000 puntos me salen 5. Ahi el problema, que se repiten los jugadores debido a los premios

Comment: Como se supone que se debe ver el resultado? Porque tal y como está tu query, MySQL está haciendo lo que pides...

Comment: listo, esta editado

Comment: Eso no responde del todo lo que pregunté. Más bien, te pedía saber qué es lo que realmente quieres de la query. Solo el nombre? Nombre y puntaje? Nombre y puntajes en un arreglo? Nombre, puntajes y premios...? En otras palabras, ¿cómo quieres que sea vea el resultado de la query?

Comment: Quiero que se vea la query con el nombre y los puntos. Filtrados por los que tienen premio y están vivos ( de ahí la fecha 0000-00-00

Answer (score 0):

El "problema" recae en que, al hacer agrupaciones, se generan filas por cada registro único no agregado/acumulado.

En otras palabras, si tienes 10 veces el mismo jugador en una tabla, pero en la misma tabla ese jugador tiene 10 puntajes diferentes y quieres agrupar por jugador, vas a obtener 10 registros de todos modos (¿Cómo sabe MySQL cuál de las 10 entradas del jugador tomar, si no la pediste explícitamente?). El problema se ve con `awards` por eso, pero pudo generarse por puntaje también.

La solucion es sencillamente no seleccionar las columna de premios.

```sql
SELECT 
    players.playerID, 
    lastName, 
    SUM(points) AS AllPoints
FROM players
    INNER JOIN players_teams ON players.playerID = players_teams.playerID  
    INNER JOIN awards_players ON players.playerID = awards_players.playerID  
WHERE award IS NOT NULL 
    AND deathDate = "0000-00-00"
GROUP BY players.playerID, lastName
HAVING SUM(points) > 30000
```

Algo a tener en cuenta, no obstante, es que, ahora que no se esta agrupando por `award`, la query va a sumar tambien los totales de los puntos. O sea, en lugar de ver 5 registros de Abdul con puntajes 191935.0, 230322.0, 383870.0, 191935.0 y 76774.0, verás solamente uno con 1074836.0 puntos (Según la info de ejemplo que das). No hace falta **ver** la fecha de fallecimiento si es un filtro estatico, por lo que también puedes no incluirla en el `SELECT`.

Si esto no es lo que requieres, entonces te sugiero hacer un [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com) con las tablas e información de prueba para poderte ayudar más a detalle (Asegúrate de elegir tu versión de MySQL).

Comment: Pero el problema es, como acabo de editar, la suma de los puntos una vez que realizo este filtro está mal. Como puedes ver arriba ahora la tabla me da esos valores donde solo hay cinco jugadores por encima de 30.000 puntos mientras que si hago ese filtro me da que un jugador tiene más de 1 millón de puntos

Comment: Además que si quitas el "award" de "select" te da un error ya que no lo estas poniendo ahi y si en "having"

Comment: Para lo segundo, mueve el filtro de `award` y la fecha de muerte, ya que estamos, a la sentencia `WHERE`. De lo primero, alli me confudiste. Te puedo asegurar que MySQL no está sumando mal. La BD solo suma lo que le pides que sume. La query de mi respuesta ignora los premios en el resultado (Solo ve que haya premios) y suma todo lo que encuentre de un jugador dado. De allí que tenga por encima del millón (Lo que es correcto, no? Un millón es mayor que treinta mil). Viendo que no estoy entiendiendo lo que quieres, te sugieron hacer el fiddle para poder ver la estructura de las tablas y datos.

Comment: el problema lo puedes ver con el ejemplo de las mini tablas donde por ejemplo Abdul aparece 3 veces y por lo tanto al hacer la suma se suman 3 veces su máximo de puntos

Comment: Si, porque eso es lo que hace la función agrupativa `SUM()`. De alli que te diga que no entiendo entonces qué es lo que requieres. Ahora mismo lo que aparentemente creo que quieres, es una lista de jugadores (y solo jugadores) con más de 30000 puntos con un premio, pero no sé de dónde vienen los puntos, o si se deben considerar solo jugadores que solo tienen más de 30000 puntos (O sea, si debo ignorar un jugador que tuvo alguna vez 29999). Necesito saber la estructura de las tablas, porque aqui el único que las conoce eres tú. De allí que te sugiera tanto hacer un fiddle, para ver cómo hacerle

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=qyq6jmu3hv   aqua estaría el código y lo que pido

Comment: En la parte izquierda del fiddle debes poner el código SQL para crear las tablas y para agregar información. En la parte derecha escribirías la query. Recuerda que tu pregunta es sobre `SQL`, no sobre `python`.

Comment: no me funciona a la hora de correr, de todo modos esta en la pregunta la información. Si filtros solo por puntos me salen cinco jugadores y si le añado más filtros en los puntos ya no se corresponden con los previamente citados y se suman debido a que un jugador gana varios títulos.

Comment: Si, el fiddle se comparte en tiempo real. Estás intentando ejecutar código python en un motor de SQL. Lo que necesita el fiddle es la estructura de las tablas que estás consultando, el DDL. No tienes acceso a esa informacion? De nuevo, recuerda que yo no conozco esa base de datos. No puedo realmente apoyarte sin mas detalles.

Comment: lo unico q puedo hacer es ponerte un link con la foto del cuadro de las tablas en el fiddle, si con eso y el condigo puedes ayudarme perfecto si no no puedo hacer nada mas.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=qyq6jmu3hv

Comment: Ok. Igual y con eso puedo inferir la estructura de las tablas.